# I want to print 'No' at end of the for loop. How should I do?

Tags: python, for-loop

I succeeded to return 'Yes' if there is a same word but .......

```
a = input()
list_a = list(a)
b = input()
list_b = list(b)

for i in range(len(a)):
    added = list_a[-1]
    list_a.pop()
    list_a.insert(0, added)

    if list_a == list_b:
        print('Yes')
        break
    else:
        continue
```

How should I return 'No' at the end of the for loop ?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a helper flag to tell you in which of the two cases you are. Default it to `False`, meaning the word by default the two lists are not the same.

```
a = input()
list_a = list(a)
b = input()
list_b = list(b)
list_are_the_same = False
for i in range(len(a)):
    added = list_a[-1]
    list_a.pop()
    list_a.insert(0, added)

    if list_a == list_b:
        list_are_the_same = True
        break
result = 'Yes' if list_are_the_same else 'No'
print(result)
```

I did one more edit - you don't need an explicit `continue` for the else, this happens anyway.

EDIT (thanks to python_learner for teaching me a new construct in python):
You can also use [else statement for for loops](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html#else-clause) and the code will become:

```
a = input()
list_a = list(a)
b = input()
list_b = list(b)
for i in range(len(a)):
    added = list_a[-1]
    list_a.pop()
    list_a.insert(0, added)

    if list_a == list_b:
        print('Yes')
        break
else:
    print('No')
```